# I have a question about 'push_back()' with reverse_iterator

Tags: c++, string, iterator, reverse-iterator

```
#include<string>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<iostream>

int main(){

    std::string str = "abc";
    std::string str2 = str;
    std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit = str.rbegin();
    for(rit+1; rit != str.rend(); rit++){
        str2.push_back('*rit');
    }
    std::cout << str2 << std::endl;
}
```

I expected the output to be 'abcba', but there seems to be an error in push_back(). Somebody help me T_T

Comment: You'd need to tell us what the error is you're getting, you know.

Comment: `str2.push_back('*rit');` -> `str2.push_back(*rit);` for starters.

Comment: @ee amil In C there are no reverse iterators.

Comment: @AKX multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]
overflow in implicit constant conversion [-Woverflow]

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I'm sorry!! It's C++

Comment: I vote to close as a typo because either you wanted to push back that literal string, in which case you need double quotes as the error explains, or you really wanted no quotes at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters there is a typo (or you wanted to highlight the expression)

```
str2.push_back('*rit');
```

It seems you mean

```
str2.push_back( *rit);
```

This declaration

```
std::vector<int>::reverse_iterator rit = str.rbegin();
```

does not make a sense. The declared object and the right expression used as an initializer have different types and there is no implicit conversion between them.

What you need is the following

```
    std::string str = "abc";
    std::string str2 = str;

    str2.append( str.rbegin(), str.rend() );

    std::cout << str2 << '\n';
```

Or you could write

```
    std::string str = "abc";
    std::string str2 = str;

    for (std::string::reverse_iterator it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); ++it)
    {
        str2.push_back( *it );
    }

    std::cout << str2 << '\n';
```

Or the for loop could be written like

```
for (auto it = str.rbegin(); it != str.rend(); ++it)
```

Comment: Oh my god the problem is solved. Thank you so much for your help!!!!!! ★★★★★★★

Comment: @eeamil If the problem is resolved you can close the question selecting the best answer.